# Getting width of HTML document to resize with the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to web development and currently building a site for a friend that is being modeled after this one: http://fulton-demo.squarespace.com/

While I have most of the elements into code and styled, I cannot figure out how to get the images and content to fill 100% of the width AND resize when the browser window is resized.  Like, take the first image on the link I provided for example...I would like it to look like this, meaning to not have *any* margins on either side and fill the browser window....and I can get it to do that, but it never shows 100% of the image and when I resize the window, nothing moves. Does that make sense?

I know this is probably a very elementary question, but I would love some insight on this. I can post any and all code if necessary. Thanks in advance guys!

EDIT: Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<main id="mainContent" role="main">
<article role="article">
    <section>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="single-item-rtl" dir="rtl">
                    <div><img src="img/6.jpg" height="600px" width="1400px" align= center/></div>
                    <div><img src="img/6.jpg"height="600px" width="1400px" align= center/></div>
                    <div><img src="img/6.JPG" height="600px" width="1400px" align= center/></div>
                    <div><img src="img/6.jpg" height="600px" width="1400px" align= center/></div>
                </div>
                <div id=logo><img src="img/SJ_WHT.png" height="170px" width="220x" align=center</div>
                <div id=text-top-carousel>
                    <h1>a better way to book creative spaces</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </section>
    <section id="info">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <h2>unique spaces <br> that inspire</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temor incididunt ut labore et                       dolore magna aliqua</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <h2>hassle free <br> booking</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temor incididunt ut labore et                        dolore magna aliqua</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <h2>share your <br>creative space</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temor incididunt ut labore et                        dolore magna aliqua</p>
        </div>
        <div class="motto">
            <h1>unleash your creativity</h1>
            <p>We focus on your artistic expression at Studio Junkey. We believe that your creative process is                              limited when the necessary resources are not available to execute your vision. <br></nr> We want to                          ensure that you find the studio space that has the tools you need to express yourself and your vision</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="contactForm">
        <div class="form">
            <h3>Want to list a studio space?</h3>
            <p>We are looking for more studios. 
               Send us your information so we can connect.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer role="footer">
    </footer>
</article>
</main>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.single-item-rtl').slick({
        rtl: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Brandon Grotesque";
src: url("fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_reg.otf") format("opentype");
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;;
padding:0;
margin: 0;
}

body {
font-family:"Brandon Grotesque";
}

#mainContent {
background: white;
width:1500px;
}

.container {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1400px;
height:600px;
text-align:center;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
position:relative;
top:-595px;
left:0em;
}

#text-top-carousel h1 {
position:relative;
top:-15px;
left:0em;  
color:white;
font-size:55px;
padding: 10px;
}

#info {
margin: 0px;
clear:both;
}

.info {
width:466px;
height:400;
padding:10px;
background:white;
text-align: center;
color:#333333;
margin: 0px;
float:left;
clear: none;
}

.info.icon {
background:black;
border:1px solid white;
width:100px;
height:100px;
padding:10px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
}


.info h2 {
padding:300px 48px 10px 48px;
font-size: 45px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
line-height: 1em;
}

.info p {
padding:15px 50px 45px 50px;
margin: 0px;
font-size: 20px;
}

.motto {
background-image:url("img/6.jpg");
text-align: center;
color: white;
clear: both;
width:1400px;
margin:0 auto;
margin-bottom:0px;
height: 600px;
}

.motto h1 {
font-size: 60px;
padding-top: 90px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.motto p {
font-size: 30px;
padding: 15px 100px 90px 100px;
}  

#contactForm {
background: #EDEFED;
margin-top:0px;
width: 1400px;
height: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
clear: both;
}

.form {
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
width:50%;
height:500px;
color:#333333;
clear:both;
}

.form h3 {
margin: 0;
font-size: 40px;
padding: 115px 185px 50px 185px;
}
```

EDIT 2: THANK YOU for all the help thus far everyone!....For those following along in the comments, the issue that I'm having now can be shown by [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxdLJ.jpg). The image carousel seems to be filling the left side completely fine, but the right side still isn't being filled at all, there's still some space between the right edge of the img carousel and the browser window when I scroll to the right.

Comment: Include your code .... and maybe screenshot with actual look and another with the desired layout

Comment: Try setting the with of the image to `100%` and the height to `auto`. This will force the image to always take up the entire width of the contain it is in while scaling the height to match its proportions.

Comment: Well, here's the complicated thing about the image, its a carousel that links to a jQuery library. Would setting the width to 100% and the height to auto still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS..

```css
.single-item-rtl img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Also remove the `height` `width` and `align` from the image tag or they'll override the CSS.

Slick tries to add arrows to the left and right side of the slider which is what is causing the issue. Since we're taking up 100% of the screen they have no place to go.

```
$('.single-item-rtl').slick({
  rtl: true,
  arrows: false
});
```

**Edit:**

Remove the width from `#mainContent` to make `.container`'s with take up 100% of the screen.

Comment: This helped! But what appears to be happening now is I have about...30px(estimated) of space on the right side between the carousel of images and the right side of the browser window when I scroll to the right.

Comment: Remove the `margin: auto;` from the CSS snippet from above and try. If it doesn't fix it can you get a screen grab and attach to your original post or link it in a comment?

Comment: I have removed the height width and align from the inline image tag. and it couldn't be the size of the image because we told it to be 100%, right?

Comment: There's always quirks with telling things to take up 100% of a given space. If you're checking all this in Chrome/FireFox open up the developer tools and inspect the image and see where it's getting the extra width that is causing it to go off screen.

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/a/4oeDz) is an image of what is happening. And thank you for all the help guys!

Comment: I think I got it!
When you declare your slick slider add this
`arrows: false`
I'll update my snippet.

Comment: Aw man! I thought that would have done it too because I forgot about those arrows! I put in arrows: false and it didn't change it though :( Excellent thinking though!

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caxmdL5v/) is what I came up with for removing the spacing.

Comment: Huh. Interesting. I have no idea, man. Could it be because the images that I'm using in the carousel are only a certain width? Because I thought we changed them in the css to be 100%....

Comment: Well your `#mainContent` is set to 1500px and `.container` is 100% OR 1400px ( max ). If your screen is larger than 1400px wide, there's going to be space to the right as `.container` is by default pushed to the left. So we can set `.container`'s `margin: auto;` and it'll be centered. There WILL be space on both sides of the screen, however. ( For screens larger than 1400px )

Comment: YES! Okay what I did was I got rid of the #mainContent width and height all together, then I set .container to a set height (600px) and width to 100%, margin 0, padding 0 and that appears to have worked!!!!! Thank you so much man! Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad I could help! If you don't mind setting this answer as THE answer that would be awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing your content inside another element is helpful.

**Note** that you have to separate between enclosing elements required for your script to work, and those used to enchance your layout.

Also my solution implies you will ever be able to specify your image width in percent **only**. You can also add maximum and minimum properties.

```css
.outer {
  width: 5cm; // arbitrary
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width img {
  width: 15%;
  max-width: 2cm;
  min-width: 5mm;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="full-width">
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use Percentage widths!!!!

Something simple like this would do:

```
.myImageClass{
  width: 50%;
  /*by not setting height, it will auto scale*/
}
```

## DEMO:

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.myFullImg{
width:100%;
}

.myHalfImage{
width:50%;  
}
```

```html
<img class="myFullImg" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt=""/>

<img class="myHalfImage" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/400" alt=""/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But the complicated part is that its not one image...its a carousel of like six images in a slideshow linked to a jQuery library file. Would this still work?

Comment: yes. I could even link you to some carousels if you wanted (i answered a question recently with some cool effects if you wnat)?